# gnome-terminal.desktop for key shortcut (ctrl+alt+t)

Tags: unity, command-line, gnome, shortcut-keys

I want to change default position of terminal.
I changed `~/.local/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop`

It works for manually opening terminal from applications menu but not for shortcut ctrl+alt+t :c

I specified following groups:

```
[Desktop Entry]
[Desktop Action New]
```

As I see 1st is for opening terminal from applications menu / launcher

The 2nd for opening by right clicking on terminal icon and selecting "New Terminal"

All i want is to know name of group that will change behavior of ctrl+alt+t

.local/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminal
Comment=Use the command line
TryExec=gnome-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal --geometry=205x10+0+1000
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
X-GNOME-DocPath=gnome-terminal/index.html
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-terminal
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=BugBuddyBugs
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.6.2
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Keywords=Run;
Actions=New;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-terminal

[Desktop Action New]
Name=New Terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal  --geometry=205x10+0+1000
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what it is that you are trying to achieve. What do you for example mean by: *I want to change default position of terminal.*? Furthermore, you can make Ctrl+Alt+T do anything you like.

Comment: Please post the contents of your current `.desktop` file

Comment: When i press ctrl+alt+t it opens terminal in upper left corner.
I want to have it at bottom of screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would set a new custom keybinding in System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts

For command use `gnome-terminal --geometry=205x10+0+1000` after creating the shortcut click in right side to set a binding.

You may want to use a slightly different binding to check out or go ahead & use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> which will unset the current for Launchers >  Launch terminal.